# A simple doubt about rigor.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Using the rigor of analysis, how do I argue that a sequence $a_{n}$, tends to be "fast" than another sequence $b_{n}$?

For exemple, considering the case where, $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to \infty$, I want to proof that $a_n b_n \to 0$

I have a intuitive idea of calculus, but I can't express it on paper.

Comment: fast about what

Comment: I assume you mean “regarding convergence”. If that’s the case, we can say that “$a_n$ converges to $L$ faster than $b_n$ if $\lim _{n \to \infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}} = 0$“.

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: In the new context, what you said can be interpreted as the definition of “$a_n$ going to $0$ faster than $b_n$ goes to infinity”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is [Little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)

For instance $n^2\to \infty$ and $e^{-n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

As $$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{n^2}{e^n}=0$$
we say that $n^2 =o(e^n)$.

In your example if $a_n\to 0$ and $b_n\to\infty;\;\frac{1}{b_n}\to 0$ if $a_n=o(b_n)$ then $$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}a_n\cdot b_n=0$$
Intuitively, $a_n$ goes to $0$ faster than $b_n$ goes to $\infty$